# Way to wear tefillin in a different nusach synagogue

Tags: tefilin, minyan, nuschaot

When praying in a minyan with a different nusach than yours, should you wear tefillin according to the minyan's nusach or according to your nusach?

Comment: Do you mean how you wrap around your hand?

Comment: Everybody does hand wrapping differently, I don't think anyone's ever noticed nor cared. The style of script *inside* the tefilin? Nobody sees that. The only issue that comes up is something like Chol HaMoed, when some communities wear and some don't.